# How to use DB::raw() with postgres?

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I try to set row number for the table but get error like this

> PDOException SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at
>   or near "@" LINE 1: SET @rownum=0 ^

here's my code

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('SET @rownum=0'));
        $bill = MonthlyBill::info()
                ->billPeriod($bill_period_id)
                ->select(DB::raw("@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row"), "monthly_bill.*", "t.*")
                ->get();
```

how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres doesn't support `@` variables - that's a mysql feature. You can use `row_number()` instead to assign a number to each row:

```
$bill = MonthlyBill::info()
    ->billPeriod($bill_period_id)
    ->select(DB::raw("row_number() over (order by some_column) row"), "monthly_bill.*", "t.*")
    ->get();
```